# Colab Pro getting disconnected automatically after 12 hours of Training Deep Learning Model using TPU Runtime

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory

I was trying to Train a Deep Learning Model using TPU Runtime in CoLab Pro. But the Runtime is getting automatically disconnected after 12 hours of Training. I have configured 70 epochs for Training and it stops at around 43 - 52 epochs. I have used Keras/Tensorflow for developing my model. For the last three days I am Training the same model but I am no able to complete the Training Process. It is frustrating that even after opting for CoLab Pro, we are not able to train the model fully.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried with Google Chrome, I was able to perform the Training for around 11 hours in Colab Pro. So I think in Google Chrome, automatic disconnection may not happen even after 12 hours. Automatic disconnection will happen if we are using Mozilla. I have tested several times in Mozilla but it is getting disconnected after 8 or 12 hours.

Comment: I'm facing a similar situation with the runtime limit and my running stops after 12 hours regardless of what browser I'm using. And, I think it may not have anything to do with the browsers, but the completion of your task might be related to the fact that every time Colab connects to a GPU/TPU it can be different than the one you connected to last time.