# Increasing Colab Pro runtime limit

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm using Colab Pro and I have no issue with the RAM when I'm using either GPU or TPU. The only problem is that my running usually takes more than 12 hours and it looks like Colab automatically stops (with no error) after 12 hours. I've reached out to their support and got no response (this is strange enough for itself that how/why Google does not have proper support for paid Colab Pro technical, not billing, issues!) I wonder if there is any way that the runtime limit can be increased to more than 12 hours? Or, has anyone experienced a similar situation or has any contact I can reach out?

A similar situation is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68015887/colab-pro-getting-disconnected-automatically-after-12-hours-of-training-deep-lea), but since there was no question asked, I'm creating this post.

Answer (score 1):

Answering this question here: the runtime limit is just simply part of the Google Pro plan as also stated on their website. For now, I had to upgrade my plan to Google Colab Pro+ to be able to 1) have longer runtime and 2) have background execution when I close my browser.

Is this ideal? No! Do I hate to spend $50 a month on Google Pro+ as a student? Yes! But that is just how Colab Pro plans work. As the [wise] man says: "it is what it is!"

Answer (score 0):

one thing i Do is keep storing the checkpoints after a specific set of intervals and after the VM gets disconnected I restart from that checkpoint.

I also use colab pro and with this method I have pretrained models which take upwards of 5 days